# MySQL dump does not properly dump

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I first run the following command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p password --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Then when I run `nano dump.sql` I get the following.

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

I am not sure if this is right or if I am running the command wrong or something.

Comment: Try running it without the redirect to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @tadman what is the redirect? I am new to mysql, I usually use phpmyadmin

Comment: The `>` character in a shell context means "redirect output to file". If you remove the `> dump.sql` part you'll see the plain output.

Comment: @tadman marcel's answer seemed to show what was wrong.

Comment: Already upvoted it, and if it solved your problem, I hope you do to!

Comment: @tadman Okay so if I put this `<` instead will it load the sql file into all the databases?

Comment: @Rixwaan yes. Because your `dump.sql` file has the `CREATE DATABASE`, `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements it will rebuild your databases. Of course use the `mysql` command instead of `mysqldump`.

Comment: @marcell What is the difference between MySQL and mysqlimport?

Comment: @Rixwaan `mysqlimport` can read data files and insert the data into the databases, it uses the `LOAD DATA INFILE` sql statement in the background. While `mysql` executes your statements. In order to restore your database from a `mysql` dump file you need to use the `mysql` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password) docs

> If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between
>   the option and the password